# How to use <link preload> to get ajax response

Tags: pagespeed, preload

Google Pagespeed insights tells me to

> Consider using `<link rel=preload>` to prioritize fetching resources
>   that are currently requested later in page load.

For the following url `/users` which is only called once via ajax

```
  $.ajax({
      url:'/user',
      success: function success(result){
        cb(result)
      }
  })
```

I tried `<link rel="preload" href="/user" as="fetch" crossorigin="anonymous">` but it does't work and gives me the following warning in the console:

> A preload for 'https://www.example.com/user'
>   is found, but is not used because the request headers do not match.
>
> The resource https://www.example.com/user was preloaded using link
>   preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load
>   event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is
>   preloaded intentionally.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am experiencing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem. You need to check all the headers carefully. If *any* of the request headers are different, Chrome will throw away the preload. (In my case, the `Accept` header was different. Wouldn't think that would matter, but when I changed them to match, it started working!)